# Unable to execute command or shell on remote system: Failed to Execute process

Tags: python, robotframework

```
SSHLibrary.Open Connection  10.118.208.225  
SSHLibrary.Login    reutadmin   Reuters01
Log To Console  D:  
${OUTPUT_DIR}   Execute Command dir
log ${OUTPUT_DIR}
```

Getting the Following output:

```
Starting test: Test.Test
20181122 19:10:53.886 :  INFO : Logging into '10.117.207.225:22' as 'reutadmin'.
20181122 19:10:58.089 :  INFO : 
Read output: Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>
20181122 19:10:58.089 :  INFO : Executing command 'dir'.
20181122 19:10:58.839 :  INFO : Command exited with return code 4294967295.
20181122 19:10:58.839 :  INFO : ${OUTPUT_DIR} = Unable to execute command or shell on remote system: Failed to Execute process.
20181122 19:10:58.839 :  INFO : **strong text**Unable to execute command or shell on remote system: Failed to Execute process.
Ending test:   Test.Test
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUEZy.png)

Comment: For your information: that return code is equal to `-1`.

Comment: my ssh skills are a bit rusty, but I don't think `dir` is a command ssh knows. Have you tried `ls`?

Comment: @Dominique, Yes its equivalent to -1. What is solution for this?

Comment: Yes  ls working thanking you  So much ..@BryanOakley

Comment: @BryanOakley, Do you know how to change the driver from C: to D:?